# std::initializer_list initialization from variable

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class L {
      public:
        L(const std::string& name, std::initializer_list<long long int> dims, float* data);
        std::string name;
        std::initializer_list<long long int> dims;
        float* data;
    };
```

I can do following

```
vector<L> input = {
                {"aaaaa", {1, 20, 1400, 1}, input_data}};
```

But I can not do following (it compiles, but the running will crash)

```
long long int a =20;
vector<L> input = {
                {"aaaaa", {1, a, 1400, 1}, input_data}};
```

Comment: It does [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1228538670b4e33e). You need nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried it? https://ideone.com/SOSjKI

Comment: It compiles. But the program crashes.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place, if it doesn't crash when you exactly replace `func({1, 20, 1400, 1});` with `long long int a=20;  func({1, a, 1400, 1});` then that suggests your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Instead of posting random snippets, please post a [mcve]. I'm guessing you initialize the `dims` data member with the `dims` constructor parameter. That will not work because an `initializer_list` is not a container, change the `dims` member to a `vector` instead.

Comment: `initializer_list` is not meant to be a general-purpose container or persistent store of data. Why did you think it was? It's just an iterable view over a compiler-allocated array, for the purposes of initialising other types of object, in which the array only lasts as long as the original expression that first created the `initializer_list`. Copying the argument into your member just gets you a copy of the iterators to that underlying array, which then goes out of scope and gives you total UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` is not a *container*. It is a reference to a temporary array. It's a type whose *purpose* is to initialize another object (hence being called an *initializer*_list), and you should not use it for *anything* other than that.

The temporary array the `initializer_list` references works like any other temporary in C++. In the case of

```
vector<L> input = {
    {"aaaaa", {1, 20, 1400, 1}, input_data}};
```

The temporary array will be destroyed immediately after this statement is executed. So you will store a pointer to a destroyed array. And therefore, your program has UB.

Now, why does your UB only lead to a crash if you use a variable?

That's because "temporary array" means whatever the compiler wants it to mean. In the case of `{1, 20, 1400, 1}`, these are all literals. So the compiler can put that array in static storage in your binary rather than making it a stack array at runtime. This saves runtime stack space, so it could be considered a reasonable optimization.

However, once you use a *variable* in the braced-init-list, that can't work (unless it's a `constexpr` variable). So the compiler is required to follow the temporary wording more strictly. Therefore, it creates a stack array, which is reclaimed after that code executes. So when you access it later... boom.

Even so, *do not rely on this.* Your program has UB either way.